# Meaning of "coordinating work"

Tags: american-english, british-english

What is the meaning of "coordinating work" in below sentence?

I am actually able to use my coordinating work in a festival toward a credit for one of my courses,

Source of info :https://youtu.be/62Z8lOWm7mg?t=888

Answer (score 1):

“Coordinating work” is a very vague phrase beloved by people who prefer an impression of importance over clarity of purpose. Technically, it should mean ensuring that the work of different people or organizations is consistent with reaching a shared goal; this requires monitoring actions or communicating intentions or both. In practice, it may mean almost anything.

Comment: It says: coordinating work **in a festival**.

Comment: Where it is used does not make its meaning any clearer. Cordinating what? Coordinating whom?

Comment: Sure it does, the coordinating work at a festival, school event, etc. etc. would all involve different tasks. Also, the "beloved by people who prefer an impression of importance" is a bridge too far.

Comment: I've known dozens of people who've "assisted" at festivals over the years (litter picking, serving free or paid-for food & drinks, etc.). Nearly always because if you put in a few hours "work" like that, you don't have to *pay* to be there. But I don't think any of them would have said they're "coordinating" anything - that's usually something only a small number of full-time employees of the festival organisers do. So if the OP really *was* doing work at that level, it's potentially gonna get brownie points on a CV.

Answer (score 0):

"Coordinating" is a verbal noun. Here it is acting as a noun adjunct modifying "work." It means something like "my work related to coordinating things" or "my work involving coordinating things."

Answer (score 0):

Sample:
I am actually able to use my coordinating work in a festival toward a credit for one of my courses,

coordinating work in a festival can refer to all the tasks involved in organizing  festival, such as:

- selling tickets
- booking a venue
- booking performers
- booking other vendors (food, etc.)

etc. etc. And these activities have to be coordinated for a festival to be successful. Obviously, for that list, which is partial, a calendar is a must. Making it all happen on the right date and time is an example of coordination.